# Convert an sql statement into a php query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I am trying to convert this code

```
  INSERT INTO destTable
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,... 
FROM srcTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM destTable 
                 WHERE (srcTable.ID=destTable.ID)
                 )
```

into a PHP query. This is what I have so far but its wrong.

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO ' . $targetDB . 'SELECT * FROM' . $sourceDB . 'WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM' . $targetDB . 'WHERE ('. $targetDB . '`.` ID ='. $sourceDB . '`.` ID)'
```

Can you adjust it to make it correct?

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Your backtics are not correct

Comment: `mysql_query('INSERT INTO ' . $targetDB . ' SELECT * FROM ' . $sourceDB . ' WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ' . $targetDB . ' WHERE ('. $targetDB . '.ID = '. $sourceDB . '.ID)'`

Comment: I just adjusted the line and not sure about its functionality. The thing is you totally missed the spaces. For instance your code would be like `FROMdestTableWHERE ...` and also checkout the dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something the following using PDO and a whitelist array for validating your table variables:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'your_database');
define('DB_USER', 'your_username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

try {
    //Make your connection handler to your database
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));

    $tables = array('table1', 'table2', 'table3');
    if (in_array($targetDB, $tables) && in_array($sourceDB, $tables)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $targetDB (SELECT * FROM $sourceDB WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $targetDB WHERE $targetDB.ID = $sourceDB.ID))";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        echo 'Wrong tables';
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just missing some space and added unnecessary quotes

```
'INSERT INTO ' . $targetDB . ' SELECT * FROM ' . $sourceDB . ' WHERE 
NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ' . $targetDB . ' WHERE ('. $targetDB . '.ID ='. $sourceDB . '.ID)'
```